# Primeng datatable issue with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am using Primeng(5.1.2) version to display grid data, I would like to expand the row of the row to show additional details.

```
highlightRow(rowData: any, rowIndex: number) {
    return ((this as DataTable).isRowExpanded(rowData)) ? 'ui-state-hightlight' : '';
}
```

I am getting an error saying that "**Cannot read property 'isRowExpanded' of undefined**".I don't find any clue why this issue is happening...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the DataTable thru the arguments and avoid using this.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="values" #dt>
</p-table>
```

When you call to the function you pass the "dt" reference and then in your function

```
highlightRow(dt: any, rowData:any, rowIndex: number){ 
   ....
}
```

Comment: I tried but same issue is with isRowExpanded of undefined.

Comment: dt.isRowExpanded(...) is giving you undefined?

Comment: I m getting "dataTable.isRowExpanded is not a function"

Comment: Can you put the code where you call to the highlightRow function ?

Comment: I m calling the method from [rowStyleClass]="highlightRow" like this on <p-dataTable...>

Comment: So that way you don't send the dt reference from the template to the controller and because of that is undefined. I don't know it this will work because [rowStyleClass] is a directive but try this: [rowStyleClass]="highlightRow(dt)" and in your controller's function set the arguments like I put in my reply and call dt instead of datatable or 'this'